# Сопоставление таблиц ASP.NET EF6

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, mvc

Имеется БД со следующей структурой:

[image: Структура БД]

В рамках одного проекта могут работать несколько подрядчиков, причем с одним и тем же подрядчиком может быть заключено несколько договоров. Требуется отобразить данные в таком формате:

[image: Желаемая структура вывода]

Каким способом возможно это сделать не изменяя структуру БД?
Я создал DbContext, содержащий затрагиваемые таблицы, в самих моделях добавил virtual свойства для обращения к связанным записям. Но, как теперь корректно вывести данные в желаемой структуре?

Comment: Куда требуется вывести данные?

Comment: @V-Mor на HTML страницу, которую будет смотреть пользователь. Страница строится с Razor.

Comment: Я вот не пойму: откуда у веб-разработчиков такое нежелание указывать язык программирования? PS: и лучше бы вместо диаграммы БД получить код сущностей и контекста.